# Does this subset of $C(S^2)$ seperates points?

Tags: general-topology

On the sphere $S^2$ we consider the real-valued functions
$$f(x,y,z)=x+y+z, g(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx.$$
Does $\{f,g\}$ seperate points? What if we add the function $h(x,y,z)=xyz$?

I have absolutely no clue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\left(f(x,y,z)\right)^2&=(x+y+z)^2\\
&=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)\\
&=1+2g(x,y,z)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, if $g(x_0,y_0,z_0)=g(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, then $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\pm f(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.

Can you find points $p=\langle x_0,y_0,z_0\rangle$ and $q=\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$ in $S^2$ such that

- $p\ne\pm q$, and
- $g(p)=g(q)$?

If you can, note that either

- $f(p)=f(q)$, in which case $f$ and $g$ do not separate $p$ and $q$, or
- $f(p)=-f(q)=f(-q)$, and $g(p)=g(-q)$, so that $f$ and $g$ do not separate $p$ and $-q$.

I’ll leave the case $\{f,g,h\}$ to you for now; it should be more accessible once you’ve worked through the first part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found $p=(1,0,0), q=(0,0,1)$, because then $g(1,0,0)=0=g(0,0,1)$ and $f(1,0,0)=1=f(0,0,1)$. This proves $\{f,g\}$ is not point-seperating. This is correct, right? I will now try the case with $\{f,g,h\}$!

Comment: @JBIBB: Yes, that’s essentially the example that first occurred to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(1,0,0) =f(0,0,1) \wedge g(1,0,0) =g(0,0,1)\wedge h(1,0,0) =h(0,0,1)$ but $(1,0,0)\neq (0,0,1)$ Thus $\{f,g,h \}$ does not separate points on sphere.